# How can we used lightning:checkboxGroup in aura iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

cmp code:

table body is as below:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Products}" var="prod">
<tr>
<th>
<lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" label="" options="{!prod}" value="{!v.value}" onchange="{!c.checkboxSelect}"/>
</th>
<td>
<div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!prod.Name}</div>
</td>
<tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

js code:

```
checkboxSelect:function(cmp,event,helper){
 var changeValue = event.getParam("value");
  alert('changeValue'+changeValue);
}
```

Am not able to see checkbox for above code in component and would like to know how to use lightning:checkboxGroup in aura:iteration

Comment: is `Products` data type is `List` if yes what of list of Item data type? `options` of  `lightning:checkboxGroup` should be 'List` type. so your `Prod` attribute data type should be `List` type

Comment: yes it is of type list .But i was not able to see the checkbox on screen but when i used UI:inputcheckbox it worked

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how your data format coming to `aura:iteration` i just take the list of list of Items for `aura:iteration` for testing.

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                        [{'label': 'Ross', 'value': 'option1'},{'label': 'Rachel', 'value': 'option2'}],
                                                         [{'label': 'randy', 'value': 'option3'},{'label': 'paul', 'value': 'option4'}],
                                                         [{'label': 'tuffy', 'value': 'option5'},{'label': 'eric', 'value': 'option6'}]
                                                        ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" default="option1"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="prod">
        <tr>
            <th>                
               <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Checkbox Group"
                             label="Checkbox Group"
                             options="{!prod }"
                             value="{! v.value }"
                             onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
   </aura:iteration>



</aura:component>
```

Comment: I have a List of records Standard products object with some fields like name and other custom fields. I want to have checkbox for each of the record displayed as table.Hence i wanted to used lightning checkbox instead of UI:inputCheckbox.I set the v.products attribute in doinit.But check box is not displaying on UI

Comment: can you update your Question, in your comment your expecting `lightning:input` type `checkbox` but your question you mentioned lightning:checkboxGroup

Comment: No i want to use  lightning:checkboxGroup  in aura iteration but its not working while UI:inputCheckbox is working .I wanted to know if lightning:checkboxGroup  works in aura:iteration